# Cannot resolve method 'getRoot()' when using viewBinding

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I'm using viewBinding in my project which works perfectly. But I have an issue where `getRoot()` cannot be resolved in this line `View view = binding.getRoot()`. My code runs fine without any crashing, but I want the error to go away and just can't seem to fix the issue. I've tried disabling and re-enabling viewBinding, Invalidating caches and restarting and cleaned the project but this annoying error just doesn't seem to go away.

Here's my code

build.gradle

```
...
viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
...
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        ...
}
```

activityMain

```
...
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorSurface"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally fixed it!!

I read in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) that `binding.getRoot()` gets the root view(the outermost view) in the corresponding layout. So I figured I'd give the root view an id and call that id instead.

**activity_main**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        ...>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.root;
        setContentView(view);
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I know that your solution works, but it is kind of a work-around.

My problem came from the fact that my root view was <layout> which is not qualified to be a root view.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped solved the mystery.  I have found that I need to add "dataBinding true" to have getRoot() for <layout>